# Does Request.Url.Host include the subdomain?

Tags: c#, url, request, host

e.g. for mail.google.com would it return google.com or mail.google.com? 
I can't actually test it myself

Comment: Why can't you test it for yourself?

Comment: Because I'm changing an already live system. I can't deploy this. Running locally gives me localhost for Request.Url.Host

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It does include subdomain (e.g. mail.google.com)

Answer (score 9):

You can save yourself from the headache of waiting for answers by reading [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) on Msdn.

```
A String that contains the host name. This is usually the DNS host name or IP address of the server.
```

If the requested DNS record is a subdomain, that's the record it will return. Subdomains are still there own records in a zone file, so its not going to return just the root domain because that's not the same record, nor request.

I was also curious as to why you couldn't test this, but if its because of the lack of an internet connection (maybe you're posting from mobile I don't know) you can add your own records to the Windows HOSTS file and test locally.

Comment: Harder to test when you're on localhost