# Get all the subdomains from a url in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

how get all the subdomains from a url

**for example** I have this url: www.fk8.ir

and this url have 4 subdomains for example:

1. test1.www.fk8.ir
2. mytest.www.fk8.ir
3. sample.www.fk8.ir
4. stack.www.fk8.ir

**input is**:
www.fk8.ir

**output:**

test1.www.fk8.ir

mytest.www.fk8.ir

sample.www.fk8.ir

stack.www.fk8.ir

Comment: I am curious how does one determine sub domains from a url in general ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131989/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-subdomains-of-a-domain

Comment: Request.Url.Host [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593456/does-request-url-host-include-the-subdomain) for more info

Comment: @isxaker: in the case of the question's scenario, will `Request.Url.Host` hold multiple subdomain values ? I tried running a sample on his url but I am having timeout problems for some reason (likely firewall here)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx